# r optimization function with formula for constrains

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I need to optimize a function, say `g(x)`, where `x` is vector and `g` is an analytic function.

The problem is that I need to optimize with a constraint (analytic) function `c(x)` which gives a scalar as an output, i.e the constraint is `c(x) > k` for some `k > 0`.

`constrOptim` only allows to give a constrain for every field separately.

Advices?

Comment: Your question is too broad and appears to be looking for a tool. Please provide the code you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I think it’s pretty clear where OP got stuck: you simply cannot parametrise `constrOptim` in the way desired here. But yeah, this looks like an off topic question (which is a shame; I wish these questions were on topic here).

Comment: Have a look at CRAN, Task Views, Optimization. A direct [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Comment: Library `nloptr` supports that kind of optimization.

Comment: I believe you want to solve a problem with a nonlinear objective and a nonlinear inequality constraint. There are some possibilities such as `Rsolnp` and  `ipoptr`. Indeed `constOptim` only allows linear inequality constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the right tool - nloptr package. A very robust package where I can define functions for the optimization (g) and constraint (c). Also I can define upper and lower bounds for each of the variables separately, and use different king of optimization methods.